# How to migrate a recursive table?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table, `category`, which has 3 columns, `id`, `parent_id` and `name`.

I have several tables like this, and I want to consolidate them into one. At present, their IDs will clash (not unique across DBs) so I need to re-ID them. If I make `id` an `auto_increment` I can copy all the other columns over just fine, but then `parent_id` won't link up properly anymore. Is there some magical way I can get the `parent_id` to point to the correct new ID?

Looking for something like

```
INSERT INTO newtable (parent_id, name) SELECT ???, name FROM oldtable
```

Comment: I imagine you could add an old_id column so that you'll still have the original id and you can run successive updates to the table to modify all the `parent_id`s to point to the new auto_inc ids.  You would obviously have to kill any foreign keys requirements on the table first and reinstitute them after all the changes were made

Comment: No magic I think, you'll have to add another table that holds the old_id and new_id

Comment: @Patrick: Ah, thought I might have to do that. @rene: I think using 1 extra column is easier than a whole extra table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you could add an old_id column so that you'll still have the original id and you can run successive updates to the table to modify all the parent_ids to point to the new auto_inc ids. You would obviously have to kill any foreign keys requirements on the table first and reinstitute them after all the changes were made – [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94374/patrick)

Answer (score 1):

How about

- Generate a new table with a column containing the name of the old table and old id (oldid, oldtablename) along with a new ID
- Add a new column 'newparentid'
- Update each row's newparentid to be (`SELECT newid FROM newtable nt WHERE oldtablename = row.oldtablename  and nt.oldid = row.parent_id`)